# Can a US citizen enter the Schengen area without a visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, us-citizens, latvia

Can a US citizen travel from USA to Latvia without visa?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: The answer to this depends on your nationality, not where you are flying from. If you are a US citizen, then yes, you do not require a visa for Latvia or any other Schengen member state.

Comment: Also please refrain from embedding hidden links into the body of the message otherwise it would be considered spam and dealt with accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search uncovered [the official website of the Latvian ministry of foreign affairs which states that US citizens can enter Latvia without needing a visa](http://www.mfa.gov.lv/en/consular-information/countries-whose-citizens-may-enter-latvia-without-a-visa) for a maximum stay of 90 days out of a 180-day period:

> ### Countries whose citizens may enter Latvia without a visa
>
> #### Stay of up to 90 days in any 180-day period
>
> [...] United States of America